# How to change this recursive SQL query to include another column in the end result

Tags: sql

I have this sql query which does a recursive search:

```
            WITH RECURSIVE RecursiveAppsessions AS (
            SELECT ID, ROOTAPPSESSIONID
            FROM appsession
            WHERE ID IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT ANALYSISRESULTS.APPSESSIONID
                FROM appsession
                JOIN APIAPPLICATION ON APIAPPLICATION.ID = appsession.APIAPPLICATIONID AND APIAPPLICATION.NAME LIKE '%test%'
                -- **this appsession.ID**
                JOIN PROPERTY ON PROPERTY.APPSESSIONID = appsession.ID AND PROPERTY.NAME = 'test' -- **this appsession.ID**
                JOIN PROPERTYITEM ON PROPERTYITEM.PROPERTYID = PROPERTY.ID
                JOIN ANALYSISRESULTS ON ANALYSISRESULTS.ID = PROPERTYITEM.ANALYSISRESULTSID
          
            )
            UNION ALL
            SELECT a.ID, a.ROOTAPPSESSIONID
            FROM appsession AS a
            INNER JOIN RecursiveAppsessions AS ra ON a.ID = ra.ROOTAPPSESSIONID
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM RecursiveAppsessions
        WHERE ROOTAPPSESSIONID IS NULL;
```

which returns

```
ID  ROOTAPPSESSIONID
33738427    Null
```

It works fine, but at the end I would like to display also the appsession.ID from that subquery (in bold). Tried many things but it all error out in that recursive query:

```
ID  ROOTAPPSESSIONID APPSESSION_ID
33738427 Null         432432423
```

Comment: Why Dont you add the appressionID in the CTE?!
`WITH RECURSIVE RecursiveAppsessions AS (
    SELECT ID, ROOTAPPSESSIONID, appressionID
    FROM appsession
    WHERE ID IN (
        -- remaining code here  
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.ID, a.ROOTAPPSESSIONID, a.appressionID
    FROM appsession AS a
    INNER JOIN RecursiveAppsessions AS ra ON a.ID = ra.ROOTAPPSESSIONID
)
SELECT *
FROM RecursiveAppsessions
WHERE ROOTAPPSESSIONID IS NULL;`

Comment: @SenthilPNathan Thanks for the comment. Because it is not the source appressionID that I want, but the appressionID of the ANALYSISRESULTS.APPSESSIONID

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RootAppsessionTempTable AS
SELECT
    ANALYSISRESULTS.APPSESSIONID,
    appsession.ID,
    CASE
        WHEN ANALYSISRESULTS.APPSESSIONID IS NOT NULL THEN ANALYSISRESULTS.APPSESSIONID
        ELSE appsession.ROOTAPPSESSIONID
    END AS ROOTAPPSESSIONID
FROM appsession
LEFT JOIN APIAPPLICATION ON APIAPPLICATION.ID = appsession.APIAPPLICATIONID AND APIAPPLICATION.NAME LIKE '%test%'
LEFT JOIN PROPERTY ON PROPERTY.APPSESSIONID = appsession.ID AND PROPERTY.NAME = 'test'
LEFT JOIN PROPERTYITEM ON PROPERTYITEM.PROPERTYID = PROPERTY.ID
LEFT JOIN ANALYSISRESULTS ON ANALYSISRESULTS.ID = PROPERTYITEM.ANALYSISRESULTSID;

WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    SELECT ID AS source_id, ROOTAPPSESSIONID AS target_id
    FROM RootAppsessionTempTable
    WHERE APPSESSIONID IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.source_id, tt.ROOTAPPSESSIONID AS target_id
    FROM RecursiveCTE r
    JOIN RootAppsessionTempTable tt ON r.target_id = tt.ID
    WHERE tt.ROOTAPPSESSIONID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT r.source_id AS source_id, r.target_id AS target_id
FROM RecursiveCTE r
LEFT JOIN RootAppsessionTempTable t ON r.target_id = t.ID
WHERE t.ROOTAPPSESSIONID IS NULL;
```